# Include label into Google mail address

Tags: gmail

I have seen that it is possible to label e-mails by using tags in the e-mail address. For example if my address is `myaddress@gmail.com` then it is possible to send e-mail like `myaddress.offer@gmail.com` where `offer` is a tag. How to enable this feature in Gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail supports address tags using the **`+`** separator. This is always enabled, however, there is no automatic labelling – you have to manually create filter rules to match each "To:" address.